# AlarmManager only firing when date is now

Tags: notifications, alarmmanager, alarm, android-pendingintent

For some reason, my alarm only fires when the date is now , e.g. 12.10pm if it is 12.10pm. And all other dates set are not fired. I am using AlarmManager and a bit puzzled by it. Can anyone help

This is the method I set the alarm in a class

```
/**
     * Set up alarm from user input
     */


public void setUpAlarm() {

    // get the time reminder hour and minute from user's input time value
    String[] timeVals = time.split(":");
    int hourOfDay = Integer.parseInt(timeVals[0].trim());
    int minOfDay = Integer.parseInt(timeVals[1].trim());

    // get the Date from User date value

    String[] dateVals = date.split("/");
    int day = Integer.parseInt(dateVals[0].trim());
    int month = Integer.parseInt(dateVals[1].trim());
    int year = Integer.parseInt(dateVals[2].trim());

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    // set calendar based on user input
    if (month == 1) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
        System.out.println("jan");
    } else if (month == 2) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.FEBRUARY);
        System.out.println("feb");
    } else if (month == 3) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MARCH);
        System.out.println("march");
    } else if (month == 4) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.APRIL);
        System.out.println("april");
    } else if (month == 5) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MAY);
        System.out.println("may");
    } else if (month == 6) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JUNE);
        System.out.println("june");
    } else if (month == 7) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JULY);
        System.out.println("july");
    } else if (month == 8) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.AUGUST);
        System.out.println("august");
    } else if (month == 9) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.SEPTEMBER);
        System.out.println("september");
    } else if (month == 10) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.OCTOBER);
        System.out.println("october");
    } else if (month == 11) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.NOVEMBER);
        System.out.println("november");
    } else if (month == 12) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.NOVEMBER);
        System.out.println("december");
    }

    // set year
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    // set day
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    // set hour of day
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
    // calendar set Minute of Day
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minOfDay);

    // set AM or PM
    if (hourOfDay < 12) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
    } else {
        calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
    }

    // create intent for alarm
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(confirmTaskForm.this,
            MyAlarmReceiver.class);

    // create pending intent
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(confirmTaskForm.this, 0,
            myIntent, 0);
    // set-up alarm manager
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    // send pendingIntent to alarmManager
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            pendingIntent);

}
```

and this then fires the broadcast receiver

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Feeder class sending data to MyAlarmService
 * @author Aaron
 *
 */
public class MyAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    int taskID ;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
           context.startService(service1);

    }

}
```

and then the notification

```
package com.example.prototype4.alarm;

import com.example.prototype4.MainActivity;
import com.example.prototype4.R;
import com.example.prototype4.Points.Achievments;
import com.example.prototype4.database.DatabaseHelper;
import com.example.prototype4.home.TaskListView;
import com.example.prototype4.task.Task;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Main Alarm functionality for Alarm is performed here
 * 
 * @author Aaron
 * 
 */
public class MyAlarmService extends Service {

    NotificationManager mManager;
    DatabaseHelper db;
    int taskID;
    Task currentTask;
    String taskTitle;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        //instantiate database
        db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "static-access", "deprecation" })
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        // get current task
        try{
            currentTask = db.getLastTaskFromDatabase();
            taskTitle = currentTask.getTaskTitle();



        // update task with deadline = true

        currentTask.setDeadline("true");
        db.updateTask(currentTask);

        mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(
                        this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),
                MainActivity.class);

        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_app_logo,
                "Task Deadline Has Passed!", System.currentTimeMillis());

        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent1,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(), "Task: ",
                "Make sure you complete task : " + taskTitle,
                pendingNotificationIntent);
        mManager.notify(0, notification);

        }catch(CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            System.out.println("Task has already been completed before deadline fired");
        }catch(NullPointerException e){
            System.out.println("Task cannot be obtained after it has been completed");
        }

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Comment: Could it be to do with setting multiple alarms if a user sets more than one?

Comment: Your alarm is probably firing "now" because you are passing it a time in the past instead of in the future. You should add debug logging to print out the actual date/time value that you pass to `AlarmManager.set()`